# More efficient jQuery html elements array double brackets command?

Tags: jquery

How do I avoid doing the following:

```
$($(".navigation li.level0")[1]).do()
```

I want:

```
$(magic).do()
```

Is there anything more efficient than the first line?

Comment: `$(htmlElementArray[1]).do()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer for updated question**

You can use either of the following instead of array representation.

```
$(".navigation li.level0").eq(1).do() //eq() function
```

```
$(".navigation li.level0:eq(1)").do() //css selector
```

**First answer**

You can use this.

```
$(htmlElementArray[1]).do()
```

instead of `$($(htmlElementArray)[1]).do()`.
This is better because it makes just a single access to the array `htmlElementArray`.

Doing `$(htmlElementArray)[1]`, will convert all items in `htmlElementArray` to jQuery object, then get the second of them as a normal JS object again, which is a unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Is that crossbrowser safe?

Comment: @user3621758 Yes. There is no risk in doing this, as long as the `htmlElementArray` is intact.

Comment: I went back and rechecked my code and my problem isn't as simple as that. Thank you! Please read the question again?